# Run pytest via IDLE gui

Tags: python, python-idle, pytest

I have installed python 3.4.2 and then ran `pip install -U pytest` to install pytest.

I have the following example script:

```
# content of test_sample.py
import pytest

def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 4
```

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> in IDLE it doesn't seem to run anything. How do I get to test my script via IDLE?

*UPDATE*
I tried to add `pytest.main()`, but I received an error.

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 32, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 85, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 413, in __call__
    return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 424, in _docall
    res = mc.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 315, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 27, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = __multicall__.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 315, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 636, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 747, in parse
    self._preparse(args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 719, in _preparse
    args=args, parser=self._parser)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 413, in __call__
    return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 424, in _docall
    res = mc.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 315, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 49, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    capman.init_capturings()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 78, in init_capturings
    self._capturing.start_capturing()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 257, in start_capturing
    self.in_.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 345, in start
    raise ValueError("saved filedescriptor not valid anymore")
ValueError: saved filedescriptor not valid anymore
```

Comment: Run test_sample.py in the console to determine whether Idle has anything to to with the failure or not.  Your title implies that you think 'yes'.  I suspect 'no', but would like to know.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue in IDLE only. Running via the command line there is no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding pytest.main() to the bottom of the script.

Check out: http://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests for some of the different options and the syntax.

Edit:
When running in IDLE, you'll also need to start pytest like this: `pytest.main("--capture=sys")`

Comment: It seems that I get some kind of error. I've updated my answer with the stacktrace in it.

Comment: @Marnix I've updated my answer to prevent getting this error when running in IDLE

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have yet time to try it out myself.

Comment: Yes this works! And if you just want to run the tests in the current file you can use `pytest.main("test_sample.py --capture=sys")`